# Updating a PM2 script file to use maximum cores

Tags: node.js, raspberry-pi, pm2

I have been using PM2 for years now and i've only just noticed that it is using a single core of my Raspberry Pi 3. I now want it to use all 4 cores in cluster mode, so when heavy processing is happening in one of the cores, my application doesn't hang up and softlock for a few seconds.

I have found the file that is responsible for handling the PM2 process of my application at

```
/etc/systemd/system/pm2-userNameGoesHere.process
```

Opening this file gives me what I assume to be the config files for PM2. I don't know what I need to add to this file in order to set the number of cores to 'max'.